# Finding the equation of a line normal to a curve and perpendicular to a line.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equation(s) of the line(s) normal to the curve $g(x)=4x^2 + 6x + 1$ that are perpendicular to the line $y(x)=2x-5$.

Answer (score 2):

The slope of the line perpendicular to the line $y = 2x- 5$ (whose slope is $2$) is $-\frac 12$, since $2\cdot -\dfrac 12 = -1$.

Now, since we also want the line with slope $-\frac 12$ to be normal to the given curve at some point $(x_0, y_0)$ on the curve, the slope of the line tangent to the curve at that point must be equal to $2$.

Find $g'(x)$,

> $$g(x)=4x^2 + 6x + 1 \quad \implies \quad g'(x) = 8x + 6$$

and solve $g'(x) = 2$ to find $x_0$.

> $$g'(x) = 8x + 6 = 2 \implies 8x = -4 \iff x = -\frac 12;\quad x_0 = -\frac 12$$

Use $g(x_0) = y_0$ to solve for $y_0$.

> $$y_0 = g(x_0) = g( -1/2) = 4\left(-\frac 12\right)^2 + 6\left(-\frac 12\right) + 1 \iff y_0 = -1$$

Then you have a point  $(x_0, y_0)$ on the line with slope $-\frac 12$ and can find the equation of your desired line by using the point-slope form: $$y - y_0 = -\frac 12(x - x_0)$$

> $$y - (-1) = -\frac 12\left(x - \frac 12\right) \iff y = -\frac 12x - \frac 54 \iff 2x + 4y = -5$$

Comment: Could you help me get the y value? I'm having trouble figuring out where i'm supposed to be plugging the x value of -.5 into.

Comment: Good work! $x_0$ is indeed $-\frac 12$. Plug $x_0 = -1/2$ into $g(x)$ to solve for $y_0= g(-1/2) = 4(-1/2)^2 + 6(-1/2) + 1.$ Then use the point-slope form to obtain the equation of the desired line.